# jQuery(window) Ajax navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to resize an image when I open a page. before ajax navigation, I used function `jQuery(window)` to say that I want to do my function resize when I get in my new page. But now with ajax navigationIi just load a part of my page so `jQuery(window)` returns nothing.

```
// start page KO PART
jQuery(window).load(function(){ 
    redimensionnement(); 
}); 
// KO PART END

// resize window OK --
jQuery(window).resize(function(){ 
    redimensionnement(); 
});
```

Do you have any idea to solve my problem?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can you not just call `redimensionnement();` in the ajax callback?

Comment: What do you mean by ajax navigation? Do you use an `iframe` that you control from a parent window or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the solution !

So, to resize my image when we enter in my image page, I test if it is load in my ajax loop like this :

```
   //ajax loop for full ajax navigation
   $.ajax({
   url: link,
   dataType:'html',
   success: function(data){

        //update of my contain
        var contenu = $(data).find("#contenu");
        $('#contenu').html(contenu).fadeIn('200');


        //TEST OF LOAD IMAGE, if yes, start my resize fonction
        $("#map-carte-1").load(function(){
       redimensionnement();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

On completion of your Ajax request load the image and when image is loaded than you resize images. here is sample code which might help you how to trace image loaded.

```
// create an image object
 objImage = new Image();

 // set what happens once the image has loaded 
objImage.onLoad=imagesLoaded(objImage);

 // preload the image file
 objImage.src='images/image1n.gif';

 // function invoked on image loaded
 function imagesLoaded(obj)
 {    
    var w = obj.width();
    var h = obj.height();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is a good idea, but my image is heavy so I prefere to charge it when visitor enter in my image page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to bind it inside onload;

```
// start page KO PART
jQuery(window).load(function(){ 
    redimensionnement(); 
    // resize window OK --
        jQuery(window).resize(function(){ 
    redimensionnement(); 
    });
}); 
// KO PART END
```

Comment: I am sorry, my english is poor so I am not sure that I have clearly explain my problem.